# A beginner trying to web scrape using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm complete beginner to all of coding.

I need to scrape a list of high school football players from that [site](https://cumberlink.com/sports/high-school/football/pa-football-writers-all-state-team-class-a-a-and/article_4d286757-a501-5b5b-b3be-cfebc06ef455.html) that won all-state awards.

I dived into the problem and was led towards Python and Beautiful Soup to web scrape.

I came up with the following code, But I am having difficulty figuring out to just get the `player information`.

I am getting a bunch of titles, links, and adds, but not the information I want.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. This is what I came up with so far. Be kind.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

theurl = "https://cumberlink.com/sports/high-school/football/pa-football-writers-all-state-team- 
class-a-a-and/article_4d286757-a501-5b5b-b3be-cfebc06ef455.html"
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen (theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup (thepage, "html.parser")

print (soup.title.text)

""""""
for link in soup.findAll('p'):
   print (link.get('href'))
   print (link.text)

""""""
print (soup.find('div', {"class":"subscriber-only"}))
```

Also, If anyone can help me understand how to import it into an `Excel` file where I can have it automatically go into a chart format. I.E. (`Player`, `Position`, `School`, `Height`, `Weight`, `Year`, `Award`, etc.)

Comment: Could you share the output of your print statements?

Comment: what exactly you would like to take from the page? give us an example

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  At the moment, your main problem seems to be impatience: it will take you time to learn each of the needed techniques.  Fortunately, you have the right keywords to search tutorials.

Comment: 2018 Pa. Football Writers All-State Team: Class 6A, 4A and 2A | Football | cumberlink.com
None
© 2019 Lee Enterprises
None
Terms of Service  |  Privacy Policy
None
Cloudy. Low 37F. Winds light and variable..
None
Cloudy. Low 37F. Winds light and variable.
None
 Updated: November 19, 2019 @ 7:37 pm
None
Player of the Year: Kyle McCord, St. Joseph’s Prep
None
Coach of the Year: Calvin Everett, Harrisburg

Comment: That is only part of the output, it is too long to post in the comment section. Is there a way to post pics? A little more... Coach of the Year: Calvin Everett, Harrisburg
None
Kyle McCord, St. Joseph’s Prep – 6-3, 195 sophomore
None
Kane Everson, Harrisburg – 5-11, 180 senior
None
Cade Pribula, Central York – 6-1, 200 senior
None
Ricky Ortega, Coatesville – 6-0, 190 junior
None

Comment: Sorry Prune, I will take that into consideration and continue learning. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @iFreeSki420 check my answer and let me know if that what you looking for !

Comment: @iFreeSki420 if my answer helped you out. so please accept it.

Comment: @iFreeSki420 Welcome to StackOverflow! If you want to add something, (like expected output) please edit your question instead of putting it in a comment. `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you don't need to use `urllib` since Python already have a great module which is `requests`.

if you looking to use `print(soup.title.text)` so it's will give you the `title` of the page.

here is the correct way to loop over your specific `div` by it's `class`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://cumberlink.com/sports/high-school/football/pa-football-writers-all-state-team-class-a-a-and/article_4d286757-a501-5b5b-b3be-cfebc06ef455.html').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll('div', {"class": "subscriber-only"}):
    print(item.text)
```

Comment: Thats a great start, thanks. I will learn a bit more about formatting it in Excel. How did you get it to only grab the names and stats? I guess I don't understand why my code grabbed other information. I will learn about the requests module.

Comment: @iFreeSki420 regarding `Excel` process. kindly open a new question as it's will be totally different approach.

Comment: @iFreeSki420 https://bpaste.net/show/3UGYG what should be the year in that case?

Comment: Year would be 2018. Class would be another column with Sophomore. You are amazing, thank you!

Comment: You welcome. just open a new question in order to be able to help you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58946219/converting-a-web-scrape-into-excel